# MYSQL error with PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

This might be a noob question but I can't find anything wrong with my code and I'm still getting mysql errors.

I am using this code to submit a form to a MYSQL database ->

```
    if($forename == '' || $surname == '' || $email == '' || $address1 == '' || $address2 == '' || $terms == ''){
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'error';
    } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO dbEntry ('forename','surname','email','address1','address2','terms')
            VALUES ('$forename','$surname','$email','$address1','$address2','$terms')" or die(mysql_error());
            $results = mysql_query($sql);

            if ($results) { echo "Details added."; }

            //if (mysql_error()) echo mysql_error();

        $_SESSION['status'] = 'success';
    }

//Print query for debugging ->
echo $sql;
```

But it's throwing this error ->

> INSERT INTO dbEntry ('forename','surname','email','address1','address2','terms') VALUES ('asd','asd','asd@asd.com','asd','as','NULL')
>   Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''forename','surname','email','address1','address2','terms') VALUES ('asd','as' at line 1

I have created a table to this structure ->

```
id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
forename VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
surname VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
address1 VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
address2 VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
terms TINYINT(1)
```

I can't see any syntax errors, where am I going wrong? Apologies if I included too much info.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not surround the column names in single quotes in the insert column list.

```
INSERT INTO dbEntry (forename,surname,email,address1,address2,terms) VALUES ('asd','asd','asd@asd.com','asd','as','NULL')
```

If your column names happen to be MySQL reserved keywords, or include spaces, hyphens, or other special but valid characters, you must surround them in backquotes:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (`desc`, `space table`, `etc`)...
```

As a hint, when MySQL prints a syntax error, 99% of the time the error occurs at the exact character where the `right syntax to use near "` opening quote begins.

Comment: Fixed it, helpful tip as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO dbEntry (forename,surname,email,address1,address2,terms) VALUES ('asd','asd','asd@asd.com','asd','as','NULL')
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a handful of oddities going on there...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO dbEntry ('forename','surname','email','address1','address2','terms')
            VALUES ('$forename','$surname','$email','$address1','$address2','$terms')" or die(mysql_error());
```

Doesn't actually make sense - you're assigning a value to a string and telling the program to die (with a mysql_error()) if the string is empty - the die() should reflect the response from the mysql_query() function - you want it to die when that function returns false. Oh and as @Michael pointed out - don't wrap your field names in quotes (apostrophes) - if required, use backticks.

```
if ($results) { echo "Details added."; }
$_SESSION['status'] = 'success';
```

That means that you'll echo out "Details added" only **if** the query executes successfully - however you're assigning 'success' to $_SESSION['status'] even if the query fails.

I'd try something more like the following; I've put some escapes in - just in case you'd missed them :) Since PHP is loosely typed empty strings and (int) 0 can be evaluated as (bool) false - so `!$forename` will be equivalent to `$forename == ''`.

```
$forename = mysql_real_escape_string($forename);
$surname = mysql_real_escape_string($surname);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$address1 = mysql_real_escape_string($address1);
$address2 = mysql_real_escape_string($address2);
$terms = (int) $terms;

if(!$forename || !$surname || !$email || !$address1 || !$address2 || !$terms) {
  $_SESSION['status'] = 'error';
}

else {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO dbEntry(forename, surname, email, address1, address2, terms) "
       . "VALUES ('{$forename}', '{$surname}', '{$email}', '{$address1}', '{$address2}', {$terms})";

  $response = mysql_query($sql);
  if(!$response) {
    die(mysql_error());
  }
  else {
    echo "Details added";
    $_SESSION['status'] = 'success';
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, really helpful of you. I've added some of this. Cheers

Comment: No worries - gave me something to do while I was eating my lunch - back to work now I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's trying to insert the string "NULL" in the terms field, which is an int.

Comment: You can enter NULL into an INT field as long as it's the value NULL NOT the string "NULL" (if the field allows NULL of course).

Comment: @CD001, The "NULL" is in quotes, though. Won't that represent the string "NULL" rather than the NULL value?

Comment: yes, which is what I meant - you can use NULL in an INT field but not "NULL" ;)

Answer (score -1):

You should use no quotes for you column list. Also use a escape function to make sure you don't have any errors when you put something in the database.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO (field, field) VALUES = ('". mysql_real_escape_string( $field ) ."', '". mysql_real_escape_string( $field ) ."')";
```

Also to get better errors use this in your query function:

```
mysql_query( $sql ) or trigger_error (mysql_error());
```

Or depending if you want to keep running your script

```
mysql_query( $sql ) or die (mysql_error());
```